# vmhgfs-fuse at boot with VMware Windows 8.1 host and Ubuntu 16.04 guest

Tags: ubuntu, shared-directory, vmware-player

I am using the VMware Player with a Windows 8.1 host and an Ubuntu 16.04 guest and I have a shared folder `shared_folder` that I want to mount to a specific location at boot: `/shared_folder`. I can manually do that using the command

`vmhgfs-fuse .host:/shared_folder /shared_folder`

Now I would like to do that automatically during boot. Since I am a beginner with Ubuntu, maybe someone can point me to the solution of my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 44):

So after half a day of googling, try-and-error, 5mins after I post this question I find a working solution.
I added the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

`.host:/shared_folder /shared_folder fuse.vmhgfs-fuse allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000,auto_unmount,defaults 0 0`

Which sets the options (sources: `vmhgfs-fuse --help` and `man fstab`):

- `allow_other` "allow access to other users"
- `uid` and `gid` the user and group ID to set for files
- `auto_unmount` "auto unmount on process termination"
- `defaults` "use default options: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async."

Comment: In my case, the allow_other has solved a perms problem. uid and gid were 0 (root) until I used that parameter (obviously I was using uid=1000 and gid=1000).

Comment: That to your half a day of googling and try-and-error, you saved me going through the same pain. Your solution was exactly what I was looking for. :-)

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. I did end up wasting an hour before reaching this page :(

Comment: WARNING! Adding removable resources to `fstab` may lead to boot problems

Comment: added entries to `fstab` can (and should) be tested with `sudo mount -a` and `sudo umount -a` before rebooting the system

Answer (score 2):

I am running CentOS 7 but this handy [ArchLinux doc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VMware/Installing_Arch_as_a_guest#Systemd) saved me. I had tons of permission issues with Apache in a shared folder, and after hours of digging, I was able to enable the mount as a systemd service. After reboot all is well.

Create a service for the directory you want to mount:

```sh
$ sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/<shared folders root directory>-<shared_folder>.service
```

Using a text editor, set the service's contents to the following, replacing each `<...>`.

```
[Unit]
Description=Load VMware shared folders
Requires=vmware-vmblock-fuse.service
After=vmware-vmblock-fuse.service
ConditionPathExists=.host:/<shared_folder>
ConditionVirtualization=vmware

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vmhgfs-fuse -o allow_other -o auto_unmount .host:/<shared_folder> <shared folders root directory>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

> **NOTE**: On openSUSE, the `vmware-vmblock-fuse` service is instead called `vmblock-fuse.service`.

Make sure `<shared folders root directory>` exists as the systemd service depends on it.

```sh
$ mkdir -p <shared folders root directory>
```

Finally, enable the service.

```sh
$ sudo systemctl enable <shared folders root directory>-<shared_folder>.service
```